# MySQL. Group matches in columns by a common id

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I am codding a search page with multiple filters and I am wondering if this is the best approach to get the results.

Each result of the search has several attributes, here I am using two attributes to simplify the example.

The main 'items' table:

```
id_items
1
2
```

The 'languages' table:

```
id_languages | language_code
1              es
2              en
```

The 'attributes_one' table:

```
id_attributes_one
1
2
```

The 'attributes_one_translations' table:

```
id_attributes_one_translations | id_attributes_one | id_language_code | translation
1                              | 1                 | 1                | Oro
2                              | 1                 | 2                | Gold
3                              | 2                 | 1                | Plata
4                              | 2                 | 2                | Silver
```

The 'attributes_one_match' table:

```
id_attributes_one_match | id_attributes_one | id_items
1                       | 1                 | 1
2                       | 2                 | 1
3                       | 1                 | 2
```

The 'attributes_two' table:

```
id_attributes_two
1
```

The 'attributes_two_translations' table:

```
id_attributes_two_translations | id_attributes_two | id_language_code | translation
1                              | 1                 | 2                | 99% gold
```

The 'attributes_two_match' table:

```
id_attributes_two_match | id_attributes_two | id_items
1                       | 1                 | 1
```

The concept is one item can have 0 or more match of each attribute table, and that match can have 0 or more translations.

Here is the query I am using when the user selects the filters to get all the items that have the attribute_one 'Gold' or 'Silver' order by this attribute ascendant:

```
SELECT 
    i.id_items AS id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT aot.translation ORDER BY aot.translation DESC SEPARATOR '!¡') AS attribute_one,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT att.translation ORDER BY att.translation DESC SEPARATOR '!¡') AS attribute_two
FROM
    items i
LEFT JOIN 
    languages AS l ON l.language_code = 'en'

LEFT JOIN 
    attributes_one_match AS aom ON aom.id_items = i.id_items 
LEFT JOIN 
    attributes_one_translations AS aot ON aot.id_attributes_one = aom.id_attributes_one 
    AND l.id_languages = aot.id_language_code 
    AND (MATCH (aot.translation) AGAINST ('"Gold"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
        OR MATCH (aot.translation) AGAINST ('"Silver"' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
LEFT JOIN 
    attributes_one AS ao ON ao.id_attributes_one = aom.id_attributes_one 

LEFT JOIN 
    attributes_two_match AS atm ON atm.id_items = i.id_items 
LEFT JOIN 
    attributes_two_translations AS att ON att.id_attributes_two = atm.id_attributes_two
    AND l.id_languages = att.id_language_code 
LEFT JOIN 
    attributes_two AS at ON at.id_attributes_two = atm.id_attributes_two

GROUP BY id

ORDER BY 2 ASC
```

The result I get is:

```
id | attribute_one | attribute_two
2  | Gold          | null
1  | Silver!¡Gold  | 99% gold
```

That result is what I was expecting. Now:

```
* The table items will have around 300k entries once the data base is filled. 
* There are 28 attributes table to match with the item. 
  Each attribute table will have around 20k entries, and each translation table will have 2 
  times the entries of the table that represents.
* Each item will have from 0 to 20 match to each item table, so I think
  I wont have problems using the function GROUP_CONCAT
```

I am concern about the performance because the search filter page I am doing updates itself by ajax each time the user change one of the filters (it updates the filters and the results). The max results per page will be 1000 items, I didn't put the LIMIT in the query of the example.

I am not an sql expert so I don't really know if what I am doing is the best approach. I would appreciate some feedback.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You probably should not use 7 tables to have 7 attributes. Use might want to use one attributetable and add a column with the attribute number 1-7. And think about if you really need so many attribute levels. Apart from that I am not entirely sure what your attributes express. Are they independent from each other? I would expect that `attribute 1 = silver` (and not gold) and `attribute 2 = 99% gold` would make no sense, but it looks like you don't prevent that within your database logic.

Comment: @Solarflare thanks for your reply. That's right, silver and 99% gold doesn't make sense but I don't prevent that match in the db since is the user through a interface who create (or reuse) the attributes and does the match with the item.
I don't understand your one attributetable method.
If I'm working with rocks, doesn't make sense to have a table for the composition, other for composition details (percents of each composition), places where that rock can be found, etc? Especially if I need to search by those attributes individually. How would you simplify that? Thanks in advance

Comment: E.g. have a table `attributes(id_attributes,attributenumber)`, put all attributes from `attributes_one` in it with `attributenumber=1`, `attributes_two` with `2` and so on. `left join attributes_one` will become `left join attributes on ... and attributenumber=1`. You can do your query (assuming 28 attributes) with about 5 joins instead of about 90 joins. There are other ways depending on what you are trying to do, and it could likely be simplified more, but the basic idea is: reduce the number of tables. If something has an identical structure (like "an attribute"), put it in the same table.

Comment: A performance tip:  Instead of `MATCH ... gold OR MATCH ... silver`, do `MATCH (..) AGAINST("gold silver")`.

Comment: @Solarflare Yeah I will play with your way to save some joins, thanks man.
@RickJames to match exact words will be  `MATCH (..) AGAINST ('"Gold" "Silver"')`, right?